# Promise.all is not waiting?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am trying to learn async await. I have the below code but for some reason I get the error

```
"Cannot convert undefined or null to object" on the line:
let objArray = Object.entries(dividendFile['Monthly Adjusted Time Series']).
```

I guess this is because the promise.all at:

```
const apiData = await Promise.all([fetchPrice, fetchDividend])**
```

is not waiting?

I know that the api call itself is not wrong, it works fine when I tried it out alone, so the problem is me doing something wrong with async await.

Any idea what could be the problem?

The part I think is the problem:

```
  //API 1
    const urlData1 = { 
        url: 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=',
        theFunction: 'TIME_SERIES_DAILY', 
        symbol: tickerSymbol, 
        apiKey: key, 
        outputsize: 'compact'
    };
        const {url,theFunction,symbol,apiKey, outputsize} = urlData1
        const apiUrl1 = `${url}${theFunction}&symbol=${symbol}&outputsize=${outputsize}&apikey=${apiKey}`;
        const fetchPrice = fetch(apiUrl1) 

    //API 2
    const urlData2 = { 
        url2: 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=',
        theFunction2: 'TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY_ADJUSTED', 
        symbol2: tickerSymbol, 
        apiKey2: key 
      };
      const {url2,theFunction2,symbol2,apiKey2} = urlData2
      const apiUrl2 = `${url2}${theFunction2}&symbol=${symbol2}&apikey=${apiKey2}`;
      const fetchDividend = fetch(apiUrl2) 

      const apiData = await Promise.all([fetchPrice, fetchDividend]);  //<--- Seems to be a problem here
      const priceFile = await apiData[0].json
      const dividendFile = await apiData[1].json

  //Get data from API 1
  let getPrice = new Promise(resolve => {
    let priceArray = Object.entries(priceFile['Time Series (Daily)']) //<--- "Error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"
    let price = parseFloat(priceArray['0']['1']['4. close']);         
      console.log('price: '+ price)
      resolve(price)
  })
```

The full code:

```
app.get('/api/getStocks', (req, res) => {
  async function waitForIt() {
  const getStocks = await Stock.find() 

   const stockInfo = []

    for(const data of getStocks) {
    const tickerSymbol = data.stock
    const key = 'aKey' 

    //API 1
    const urlData1 = { 
        url: 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=',
        theFunction: 'TIME_SERIES_DAILY', 
        symbol: tickerSymbol, 
        apiKey: key, 
        outputsize: 'compact'
    };
        const {url,theFunction,symbol,apiKey, outputsize} = urlData1
        const apiUrl1 = `${url}${theFunction}&symbol=${symbol}&outputsize=${outputsize}&apikey=${apiKey}`;
        const fetchPrice = fetch(apiUrl1) 

    //API 2
    const urlData2 = { 
        url2: 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=',
        theFunction2: 'TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY_ADJUSTED', 
        symbol2: tickerSymbol, 
        apiKey2: key 
      };
      const {url2,theFunction2,symbol2,apiKey2} = urlData2
      const apiUrl2 = `${url2}${theFunction2}&symbol=${symbol2}&apikey=${apiKey2}`;
      const fetchDividend = fetch(apiUrl2) 

      const apiData = await Promise.all([fetchPrice, fetchDividend]);  //<--- Seems to be a problem here
      const priceFile = await apiData[0].json
      const dividendFile = await apiData[1].json

  //Get data from API 1
  let getPrice = new Promise(resolve => {
    let priceArray = Object.entries(priceFile['Time Series (Daily)']) //<--- "Error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"
    let price = parseFloat(priceArray['0']['1']['4. close']);         
      console.log('price: '+ price)
      resolve(price)
  })

  //Get data from API 2
  let getDividend = new Promise(resolve => {
      let objArray = Object.entries(dividendFile['Monthly Adjusted Time Series']) 
      let dividendArray = [];                                                     
      let i = 1                                                                   
      while(i<=12) {
      dividendArray.push(parseFloat(objArray[i]['1']["7. dividend amount"]))
      i++
      }

      let dividend = dividendArray.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {        
        return accumulator + currentValue;
      });
      console.log('dividend: ' + dividend)
      resolve(dividend)
    })
    const [div, price] = await Promise.all([getDividend, getPrice]); 

  stockInfo.push([data.stock,data.shares,data._id,div, price])

    } //end of for lop.
    console.log(stockInfo)
res.json(stockInfo)
  } //end of async function
  waitForIt(); 
})
```

Comment: Fetch's `Response.json()` is a function, not a property. Use `await apiData[0].json()` instead of `await apiData[0].json`.

Comment: You are so right, i totally missed to write the parantheses, I probably been working for to long to notice it.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah... debugger helps... I have never seen Promise.all() fail to do what it is supposed to. in the debugger you would see very quickly that your json simply contains something else than you expected - a function instead of a Promise returned by this function.

Just try

```
const [priceFile, dividentFile] = await Promise.all([
   fetchPrice.then(result => result.json()),
   fetchDividend.then(result => result.json())
])
```

This way you can parallelize not only the fetch, but also body parsing, although it could be turned into some nicer implementation if you just extracted some common code to functions instead of essentially copy-pasting same code for 2 requests.